# Tweepy filter utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, twitter, utf-8, tweepy

I have been working with the Tweepy and when I execute the filter of the tweepy passing non-ascii characters I have an error. For exemple, using the following command, I got the error below:

My code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(apikey[0], apikey[1])
auth.set_access_token(apikey[2], apikey[3])
api = tweepy.API(auth)
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
sapi.filter(track=['eleições'])
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./TwitterStreamingAPI.py", line 81, in <module>
    sapi.filter(track=['eleições']) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 303, in filter
    encoded_track = [s.encode(encoding) for s in track]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I would be glad if someone help me in how to solve it.

Thanks in advance,

Thiago.

Comment: Are you using Python3 or Python2?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the filter line with:

```
sapi.filter(track=[u'eleições'])
```

One does `.encode()` to convert from `unicode` to `str`. One does `.decode()` to convert from `str` to `unicode`. Since tweepy is attempting to `.encode()`, we should feed it a `unicode`.

Comment: it seems to work, but I have the same problem when I receive the tweet and perform some text treatment on it. Moreover, how would I work if I used a variable instead of the string 'eleições'?

Comment: 1) If you have a similar problem after you receive a tweet, post **that** code and ask whatever questions you have related to it. 2) How to use a variable would depend upon how you create the variable.

Comment: For excellent advice related to this subject, see http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html