# Python 3.6 :Can't save CSV file in Arabic

Tags: python, csv, tweepy

i'm trying to write my tweepy results to a CSV file in Arabic, But the output file is always in unicode example :

```
u0646 \u060c \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0646\u062a\u062e\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0648\u0631\u064a \u0628\u064a\u0631\u062c\u0639 \u0639\u0628\u064a\u062a\u0648 \u0648\u0645\u0627 \u0628\u0634\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0644\u062d\u0642 \u062d\u062a\u0649
```

my code:

```
    def on_data (self , data):
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(data)['text']
            tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
            savefile = str(time.time()) + "::" + tweet
            save = open('twitterDB4.csv', 'a')
            save.write(savefile)
            save.write("\n\n")
            save.close()
            return (True)

        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tweepy filter utf-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007898/tweepy-filter-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: To make a [mcve], eliminate tweepy and just give a sample `tweet` string that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks Mark, i have removed anything unrelated to saving the CSV file

Comment: `tweet = json.loads(data)['text']` - by the time you get here, is `tweet` looking good?

Comment: Kos, Yes, Printing tweet to console works perfectly

Comment: What is that string?